# How to fix og:url Facebook property on my website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website with share locker on domain-name.com/locker.html. It has og:url property set to domain-name.com like this:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.domain-name.com" />
```

The problem which I have is that I want my shared post on Facebook redirect users to domain-name.com like I set in my og:url property and not to domain-name.com/locker.html like it is now. Why I still see 
domain-name.com/locker.html on my Facebook shared post? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you use the debug tool to clear facebook's cache after you changed the meta tags? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Hello Igy! Funny thing I wanted to contact you through PM because I found your similar helpful post in 2011. I did everything what you suggested back then. Couldn't find PM option to contact you. Yes, I did "Fetch new scrape information" and everything appears perfect in there. I even tried creating new exact same page because I thought maybe there is some FB cache problem and then after I fetched graph data for new page I shared my page and it still showing that locker page instead my "og:url" domain. How can I reach you so you can maybe inspect my page? Do you have some email, skype?

Comment: Maybe I have to add some "href" property? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button